# Number of data entries goes up each time i add data to firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have currently made a code to add data to my firestore database, which I thought worked well until I tested it today. I have made a modal to add the data and each time I add a new item, the number of times it is added goes up. So the first time it's only added once, but the item after that is added twice and so on. I am relatively new to firebase and js so I can't figure out what is wrong. Here is my code:

This is the modal I have for input:

```
      <div id="modal-add" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <h4> Legg til elementer </h4><br />
          <form id="add-form">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; margin-bottom: 10px;"> <!-- valg av apparat -->
              <label for="apparat" style="margin: 10px 10px 0 0 ;"> Velg Apparat: </label>
              <select style="display:block; width:auto;" id="apparatusAdd" onchange="addElementApparat()" required>
                <option> </option>
                <option value="Frittstående"> Frittstående </option>
                <option value="Bøyle"> Bøyle </option>
                <option value="Ringer"> Ringer </option>
                <option value="Hopp"> Hopp </option>
                <option value="Skranke"> Skranke  </option>
                <option value="Svingstang"> Svingstang </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input type="text" id="add-navn" required />
              <label for="add-navn"> Navn </label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input type="text" id="add-verdi" required />
              <label for="add-verdi"> Verdi </label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn yellow darken-2 z-depth-0"> Legg til </button>
            <button class="btn-small red" onclick="lukkModal()"> Lukk </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I made it so the user first selects on option from the list and then I used an if-statement to add the item to the right collection in Firestore. This is my js:

```
function addElementApparat() {
  var x = document.getElementById('apparatusAdd').value;
  console.log(x);
  const addElement = document.querySelector('#add-form');

  if (x === 'Frittstående') { // legger til elementer i FX
    console.log("ADD FX");
    addElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      db.collection('Apparater').doc('FX').collection('elementer').add({
        navn: addElement['add-navn'].value,
        verdi: addElement['add-verdi'].value
      }).then(() => {  // lukker ikke modalen slik at det skal være lettere å legge til flere uten å gå ut og inn
        console.log('element successfully added');
        addElement.reset();
      });  
    });
  } else if (x === 'Bøyle') { // legger til elementer i PH
    console.log("ADD PH");
    addElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      db.collection('Apparater').doc('PH').collection('elementer').add({
        navn: addElement['add-navn'].value,
        verdi: addElement['add-verdi'].value
      }).then(() => { // lukker ikke modalen slik at det skal være lettere å legge til flere uten å gå ut og inn
        console.log('element successfully added');
        addElement.reset();
      });  
    });
  } else if (x === 'Ringer') { // legger til elementer i SR
      console.log("ADD SR");
      addElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        db.collection('Apparater').doc('SR').collection('elementer').add({
          navn: addElement['add-navn'].value,
          verdi: addElement['add-verdi'].value
        }).then(() => { // lukker ikke modalen slik at det skal være lettere å legge til flere uten å gå ut og inn
          console.log('element successfully added');
          addElement.reset();
        });  
      });
  } else if (x === 'Hopp') { // legger til elementer i VT
    console.log("ADD VT");
    addElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      db.collection('Apparater').doc('VT').collection('elementer').add({
        navn: addElement['add-navn'].value,
        verdi: addElement['add-verdi'].value
      }).then(() => { // lukker ikke modalen slik at det skal være lettere å legge til flere uten å gå ut og inn
        console.log('element successfully added');
        addElement.reset();
      });  
    });
  } else if (x === 'Skranke') {
    console.log("ADD PB");
    addElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      db.collection('Apparater').doc('PB').collection('elementer').add({
        navn: addElement['add-navn'].value,
        verdi: addElement['add-verdi'].value
      }).then(() => { // lukker ikke modalen slik at det skal være lettere å legge til flere uten å gå ut og inn
        console.log('element successfully added');
        addElement.reset();
      });  
    });
  } else if (x === 'Svingstang')  {
    console.log("ADD HB");
    addElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      db.collection('Apparater').doc('HB').collection('elementer').add({
        navn: addElement['add-navn'].value,
        verdi: addElement['add-verdi'].value
      }).then(() => { // lukker ikke modalen slik at det skal være lettere å legge til flere uten å gå ut og inn
        console.log('element successfully added');
        addElement.reset();
      });  
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Prøv på nytt");
  }
};
function lukkModal() { // knapp som lukker modalen man legger til elementer
  const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-add');
  M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();    
}
```

I know my code is not the most efficient, but again I am relatively new to this, and I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure this out. And I am sorry if this is too long. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a new event listener to the submit button, each time you call `addElementApparat`.

- So the first time you call `addElementApparat` you add the first listener, so when the user then clicks the submit button, it adds a single document.
- The next time you call `addElementApparat`, you add a second listener. So when the user then clicks the submit button, the same listener gets called twice, and two documents are added.

The possible solutions are to:

- Either only add a listener once.
- Remove the listener when it's no longer needed.

The simplest change from your current code is to remove the listener once the user has clicked the submit button. An example for one of them:

```
let listener = addElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  addElement.removeListener('submit', listener);
  db.collection('Apparater').doc('FX').collection('elementer').add({
    navn: addElement['add-navn'].value,
    verdi: addElement['add-verdi'].value
  }).then(() => {  // lukker ikke modalen slik at det skal være lettere å legge til flere uten å gå ut og inn
    console.log('element successfully added');
    addElement.reset();
  });
})
```

In your current code you'd then need to repeat this for each `if`.

---

But I'd highly recommend merging all the listeners together, as they seem to only vary in minor details.

```
function addElementApparat() {
  var x = document.getElementById('apparatusAdd').value;
  const addElement = document.querySelector('#add-form');

  var collectionName;

  if (x === 'Frittstående') { // legger til elementer i FX
    collectionName = "FX";
  } else if (x === 'Bøyle') { // legger til elementer i PH
    collectionName = "PH";
  } else if (x === 'Ringer') { // legger til elementer i SR
    collectionName = "SR";
  } else if (x === 'Hopp') { // legger til elementer i VT
    collectionName = "VT";
  } else if (x === 'Skranke') {
    collectionName = "PB";
  } else if (x === 'Svingstang')  {
    collectionName = "HB";
  } else {
    console.log("Prøv på nytt");
    return;
  }
  addElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection('Apparater').doc(collectionName).collection('elementer').add({
      navn: addElement['add-navn'].value,
      verdi: addElement['add-verdi'].value
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('element successfully added');
      addElement.reset();
    });  
  });
};
```

---

Even simpler is to use the `value` attribute of your `option` elements to store the collection name:

```
<option value="FX"> Frittstående </option>
<option value="PH"> Bøyle </option>
<option value="SR"> Ringer </option>
<option value="VT"> Hopp </option>
<option value="PB"> Skranke  </option>
<option value="HB"> Svingstang </option>
```

Now your entire `addElementApparat` function can become:

```
function addElementApparat() {
  var collectionName = document.getElementById('apparatusAdd').value;
  const addElement = document.querySelector('#add-form');

  if (["FX", "PH", "SR", "VT", "PB", "HB"].indexOf(collectionName) >= 0) {
    addElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      db.collection('Apparater').doc(collectionName).collection('elementer').add({
        navn: addElement['add-navn'].value,
        verdi: addElement['add-verdi'].value
      }).then(() => {
        console.log('element successfully added');
        addElement.reset();
      });  
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Prøv på nytt");
  }
};
```

The `if (["FX", "PH", "SR", "VT", "PB", "HB"].indexOf(collectionName) >= 0) {` checks if the collection name from the form is valid.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was just wondering about one thing. I tried the last code you provided, and the same thing happened again. Do I just need to add the "removeListener" for it to work? And will it still be possible to add several different items after each other?